# Proving a property of Subset relation on list of pairs

Tags: coq

I'm proving a simple mathematical property about subsets, for example : A subset B; which is about the fact that adding a member to set B cannot affect this relation. In the program, A and B are list of pairs. `entity_IN_listPair` checks if a specific pair is in a list of pair and `listPairEqual` checks equality of two list of pairs.  I am a bit stuck how to proceed in the proof of lemma `Lemma  addtolistPairSUB`:

```
Require Import List.
Require Import Bool.

Definition entity := nat.
Definition entityID := nat.
Definition listPair : Set :=
   list  (entity * entityID).

(* Nat equality *)
Fixpoint Entity_eq (X:_) (a b:_) : bool :=
   match a with
  | O => match b with
         | O => true
         | S m' => false
         end
  | S n' => match b with
            | O => false
            | S m' => ( Entity_eq nat (n')( m'))
            end
    end.

(* checking if an  entity is in an listPair *)
Fixpoint  entity_IN_listPair
  (entit: entity ) (lispair: listPair) : bool :=
match lispair with 
  |first::body =>               match first with
                                        |(p_one,ptwo)=> (Entity_eq (nat)(entit)(p_one )) 
                                             ||  entity_IN_listPair entit body

                                       end
 |nil => false
 end.

(* checking the equality of two listPair *)
Fixpoint  listPairSUB
           (first second: listPair) : bool :=
   match first with 
  |head::tail => match head with
                                 |(part1,part2)=> if (entity_IN_listPair part1 second)
                                                 then  listPairSUB tail second
                                                 else false
                                 end
   |nil => true
       end. 

Definition listPairEqual (firstL secondL:listPair) :=
   (listPairSUB firstL secondL) && (listPairSUB secondL firstL).

 Lemma  addtolistPairSUB: 
 forall (a b: listPair ) (c:entity * entityID),
        listPairSUB a b = true->listPairSUB (a) (c::b) = true .
Proof.
induction a.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is.  (I took the liberty of refactoring your code a little bit.)

```
Require Import List.
Require Import Bool.

Definition entity := nat.
Definition entityID := nat.
Definition listPair : Set :=
  list (entity * entityID).

Fixpoint in_listpair e (l : listPair) :=
  match l with
  | nil          => false
  | (x, y) :: l' => Nat.eqb e x || in_listpair e l'
  end.

Fixpoint subset_listpair (l1 l2 : listPair) :=
  match l1 with
  | nil => true
  | (x1, _) :: l1 => in_listpair x1 l2 && subset_listpair l1 l2
  end.

Lemma subset_listpair_cons l1 l2 p :
  subset_listpair l1 l2 = true ->
  subset_listpair l1 (p :: l2) = true.
Proof.
induction l1 as [|[x1 y1] l1 IH]; simpl; trivial.
destruct p as [x2 y2]; simpl.
destruct (in_listpair x1 l2); simpl; try easy.
intros H; rewrite IH; trivial.
now rewrite orb_true_r.
Qed.
```

Comment: That statement is false: just take l1 = [(0,0)], p = (0,0) and l2 =[].

Comment: Your original comment was asking to show that if l1 is *not* a subset of l2, it is not a subset of p :: l2. My example satisfies the premise, but not the conclusion, hence why the statement is wrong. It is hard to know how to fix it without knowing what you want; your proposal wouldn't work either.

Comment: I got your point. What I want in this theorem is based on the simple mathematical subset relation. if A subset B is true, adding any members to B doesn't affect the relation A subset B.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what the theorem proved in the answer says, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you pointed out an instance that makes it wrong (false = true in the premise that doesn't do anything to make this specific example false), I mean maybe it's not encoded correctly in Coq. I'm confused. How should I change it or it is correct? :(

Comment: I did not provide a counter example to the theorem proved above. You had written a comment before that you erased. The statement in that comment was false, and I provided a counter example to that.

Comment: My bad, sorry. You are awesome. I will ask another question related to the same definitions and it will be nice of you to help me another time. Thank you.